# Trying to understand the AVAudioPlayer in iOS development

Tags: ios, c

I'm new to iOS development and am wondering if someone could help me understand why this works? What does the @synthesize do?

In .h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

In .m

```
@synthesize player;

-(void)startMusic{
    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"audio" ofType:@"m4a"];
    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
    player.numberOfLoops = -1; //infinite
    [player play];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Object Oriented Programming, there are methods, or functions, called setters and getters. the setters set the data for a certain variable. The getters are essentially the getters of the data. with objective-c, and iOS, you don't have to provide the setters and getters for the variable you are dealing with. The @synthesize keyword is what automatically creates the setters/getters. An example using your code

For the @property you have, the compiler is doing this:

```
-(void)setAVAudioPlayer:(AVAudioPlayer *)player {}
-(AVAudioPlayer *)getAVAudioPlayer { return AVAudioPlayer var;}
```

This isn't exactly the conventions the compiler would be using, but it is just to show the setters/getters way of showing what @synthesize does. It is like an automatic creation of the getters/setters.

In your example, the way it works is when you have created the property for player, the compiler is already seeing player as an object, so it creates it as a "global" variable, meaning that you can use it in all of your .m file, not just where you play the sound

Hope this helps!